# Find the distance between multiple gameobjects in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am working on cricket like game. Consider a circular field with batsman on the center of the circle and other players are randomly distributed. How can I get direction with maximum gap from batsman to the boundary where there are no fielders, randomly populate fielders without overlapping each other and find the direction vector from batsman to the boundary? refer below image foe reference.[image: Image for reference with player in center and fielders in field]

Comment: You could calculate the angle of Player P to every other Player (1 to 8). Store the result in a list and sort it ascending. Then look through the List and find the biggest difference of two neighboring entries. This represets the left and right borders of your maximum gap. Calculate the center of this gap. That should be the optimum.