# Determining open directions/areas for player in water polo game - C#/ Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, game-physics, direction

Ok heres a fun problem I'm working on currently that maybe someone can help me with:

I have a water polo game that's in 2.5D (aka 3D but with sprites)

I'm looking to determine which directions are considered "open space" for the player to be able to drift into.

The players have sphere colliders and currently Im doing things like Physics.OverlapSphere to determine who is in the general vicinity, but to make it more realistic I want the players to be able to move to areas that are open.

I was thinking about just checking cardinal directions on a raycast of distance like 2 or 3 and keep a list of available directions the player can drift, but I'm sure theres a magical sort of mathematical formula to determine open angles or something based on where opposing players have been found in the raycast/overlapSphere.

Cant find much online to help because every google search tries to funnel me to "how to move a player in Unity" -_- haha

Any fun little tips, ideas or mathematical directions to point me in (no pun intended haha) would be appreciated and might help others who are trying to make team based games too!

Thanks (:

Comment: Is it not up to the player to decide where to move? And would the colliders not prevent them from moving into places that are not open? Or do you mean "drift" in that you want some kind of non-action motion to be applied causing players to automatically "float" into open water? I'm just a little lost on exactly what it is you want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276105/find-the-distance-between-multiple-gameobjects-in-unity